# SAS EG Is there code to run tasks within the WORK directory from another program?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

Say I have tasks and programs in my process flow.

```
ProgramA --> Dataset1 --[Query1]--Dataset2
ProgramB --> Dataset3 --[Query2]--Dataset4
```

Is it possible to construct a 'main' program ProgramC that contains code to run **only** ProgramA and Query1 in the Process flow?

Comment: Are you looking for `%include`? That'll run program from within a program

Comment: Kind of... I found that %include will work ONLY if the Programs are saved to a directory outside of the project. I would want to know if %Include can call items within the project in the same WORK directory.     If you try: 

%include WORK.Program;

ERROR: Incorrect %INCLUDE statement will not be executed. There is a syntax error.

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. I think you'll either need to save your programs in a permanent location, or try to encapsulate things within macros, as suggested here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/Call-Other-SAS-Programs-Within-a-Single-Project/td-p/151926

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mot possible as per the comment from Josh.